Handle Multiple Email and Phone fields with Data Cloud
I am in the process of setting up Data Cloud for a client. The Contact object has 2 different email fields and 5 different phone fields. I want to map all of them to the Contact Point Email/ Phone DMO, but struggling to wrap my head around.
I understand that some data transformation is needed to split a single Contact record into multiple (for each contact point) but not sure how to actually do it. I tried doing it for the 2 email fields but not sure if thats the right way to do it. And then how to go a bout the 5 phone fields ?

